# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

I have app in Angular 6 , user can follow, like, dislike etc . I am trying to save the data to the server via a post method.

When the user clicks eg follow I get the following error:

```
UserProfileComponent.html:27 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'followers' of undefined
    at UserProfileComponent.push../src/app/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts.UserProfileComponent.followButtonClick (user-profile.component.ts:46)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UserProfileComponent.html:27)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19324)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20418)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20121)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:16773)
    at core.js:17220
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:988)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:13842)
```

Here is json file in server:

```
{
  "statuses": [{
    "id": 1,
    "statusId": 2,
    "likes": 121,
    "following": 723,
    "followers": 4433
  }]
}
```

Here is service I have :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
import { Comment } from '../model/comments.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  status: Status[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  statusUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/statuses';
  commentsUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/comments';

  getStatuses() {
    return this.http.get<Status[]>(this.statusUrl);
  }

  addStatus(status: Status) {
   return this.http.patch(this.statusUrl, status);
  }

  addComments(comment: Comment) {
    return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, comment);
  }

}
```

Here is component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
import { Comment } from '../model/comments.model';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  status: Status[];
  comment: Comment[];
  numberOflikes = 121;
  numberOffollowing = 723;
  numberOffollowers = 4433;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.userService.getStatuses()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.status = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  addComments() {
    this.userService.addComments(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.comment.push(this.addForm.value);
      });
  }

  followButtonClick(statusId) {
    this.status[statusId].followers++;
    this.persistStatus(this.status[statusId]);
  }

  persistStatus(status) {
    this.userService.addStatus(status);
  }

}
```

Here is html

## Harvey Specter

New York USA

```
      </div>
      <ul class="profile_card-bottom" *ngFor="let stat of status">
        <li class="likes">
          <span class="assets-count">{{stat.followers}}</span>
          <span class="assets-title">Likes</span>
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is model for status

```
export class Status {
    id: number;
    statusId: number;
    like: number;
    following: number;
    followers: number;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Is your server returning an array or a simple object?

Comment: @Zlatko `[{…}]0: followers: 4433following: 723id: 1likes: 121statusId: 2__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)`  here is console log

Comment: Actually you are doing the patch request wrong. In your `followButtonClick` you are doing `this.status[statusId].followers++;` which actually doesn't exists in your json. Infact in your `patch` request (in your service) you have to send two parameters instead of one i.e. `1. id of the object which will be added to your url` and `2. property you want to update` actually you are doing a wrong request

Comment: Is your github upto date???

Comment: Then you messed up buddy, first `db.json` should be in assests folder `2. you haven't specified any route for /statuses` in your backend and when you are redirecting to home page it fetches `/statuses` so 404 not found. I advice you take a deep breath and understand what you are doing and work step by step, everything will be sorted out else there are many great developers in this community to help you out, happy coding buddy

Comment: @Suryan am using fake json everything works okay on backend tested that  this is not real api

Comment: I know, I have tested on my local machine after cloning your repo, you are using json-server and i even installed it in my machine right now to test, further we can move the discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182591/discussion-between-user9964622-and-suryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see you did not pass argument to your `followButtonClick()` method in html, so move your button in your `*ngFor` loop and pass `stat.id`
as mentioned @selemmn

```
<h1>
 Harvey Specter
 <span class="heart reaction">
  <i class="fa fa-heart heart" aria-hidden="true"(click)="followButtonClick(stat.id)"></i>
 </span>
</h1>
```

and also change your `followButtonClick()` method to this

```
followButtonClick(statusId) { 
 const statusToUpdate = this.status.filter(status => status.id === statusId)[0]; 
 statusToUpdate.followers++; 
 this.persistStatus(statusToUpdate); 
}
```

so as you didn't pass argument your `statusId` is `undefined` in  `followButtonClick()` so it tries to get `this.status[undefined].followers++;` and throws error that can't find property  `followers` of `undefined`

Comment: so what do I need to change ?

Comment: you need to pass your `statusId` argument to `followButtonClick()` method in `html`, so it can correctly find property

Comment: do you mean something like this :  `<button class="btn-follow" (click)="followButtonClick(stat.id)">Follow</button>` ?

Comment: but be sure that your button inside in `*ngFor` loop so your `stat` isn't undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182588/discussion-between-user9964622-and-artyom).

Comment: I am getting error :  `Error: Insert failed, duplicate id`

Answer (score 1):

You pass nothing as a parameter in the HTML part then based on the same function but with a parameter you proceed in the TS part.

Change [this line](https://github.com/throne1986/profile/blob/master/src/app/user-profile/user-profile.component.html#L27) to :

`<button class="btn-follow" (click)="followButtonClick(stat.id)">Follow</button>`

**PS:** Assuming it's named `id` of course.

Comment: Hi selem still the same problem , thanks for helping though

Comment: @user9964622 could you paste also a `console.log(this.status)` ?

Comment: `[{…}]0: followers: 4433following: 723id: 1likes: 121statusId: 2__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: @user9964622 check my answer again please

Comment: I have answered to it 20 mins ago

Comment: @Artyom and what am I supposed to do ?

Comment: @selemmn don't care, I just mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Even though `this.status` is an array, there's no gurantee that the index of a status and it's `statusId` will be the same. So you might be getting an index that doesn't exist in your `status` array and hence the undefined error

Try changing the implememtation of `followButtonClick(statusId)` like this:

```
followButtonClick(statusId) {
  const statusToUpdate = this.status.filter(status => status.statusId === statusId)[0];
  statusToUpdate.followers++;
  this.persistStatus(statusToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: let me check brb

Comment: I still get the same problem

Comment: Let me check if for you.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to open this in StackBlitz. Any reason that you could think of?

[Here's the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/throne1986/profile?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: why dont u just clone it and test in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that your userService is sending empty data, this empty data then loads into the status array. This should not happen.

You can either handle it in the userService (preferrably , which should b the code hosted at http://localhost:3000/statuses ) 
If you have no control on server side, you can fix their mistake when calling `this.userService.getStatuses()` to check if the data is valid object and not an empty one.